# Popup not reflected in dispatch

Tags: reactjs

I do post call function after dispatch i have to show some error popup but dispatch is not found. I can't able to done a popup in react. Anyone can help me resolve this issue.

```
    export const NAME = 'NAME';
export const name= ({ file, path }) => ({
  type: NAME,
  payload: { file, path },
  meta: { fetch: CREATE, resource: 'images/upload' }
});
```

Comment: Can you please check a updated code @acdcjunior

Comment: There's no `dispatch` in it. Can you show us the dispatch portion of the code as well? Could you include the error message too?